# Guice assisted inject with several factory methods and null parameters

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have this interface and simple implementation:

```
public interface Data {    
}

import java.nio.file.Path;
import javax.annotation.Nullable;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted;

public class SimpleData implements Data {
    @Inject
    public SimpleData(@Assisted @Nullable Path path) {
    }
}
```

I want to generate a `Factory` with different methods using guice.

```
import java.nio.file.Path;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;

public interface Factory {
    Data create();
    Data load(@Nullable Path path);
}
```

But the following module configuration:

```
import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Injector;
import com.google.inject.assistedinject.FactoryModuleBuilder;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(
                binder -> binder.install(
                            new FactoryModuleBuilder().implement(Data.class, SimpleData.class)
                                                      .build(Factory.class)));
        Data data = injector.getInstance(Factory.class).create();
    }
}
```

fails:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:

    1) No implementation for java.nio.file.Path annotated with @com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted(value=) was bound.
      while locating java.nio.file.Path annotated with @com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted(value=)
        for parameter 0 at SimpleData.<init>(SimpleData.java:10)
      at Factory.create(Factory.java:1)
      at com.google.inject.assistedinject.FactoryProvider2.initialize(FactoryProvider2.java:539)
      at com.google.inject.assistedinject.FactoryModuleBuilder$1.configure(FactoryModuleBuilder.java:335)

    1 error
        at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:435)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:175)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:109)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:72)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
        at Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved my problem using the annotation [`@AssistedInject`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/assistedinject/AssistedInject.html). Quote from the javadoc:

> When used in tandem with [`FactoryModuleBuilder`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/assistedinject/FactoryModuleBuilder.html), constructors annotated with @AssistedInject indicate that multiple constructors can be injected, each with different parameters.

So i add the annotation and a constructor to the `SimpleData` class:

```
public class SimpleData implements Data {
    @AssistedInject
    public SimpleData(@Assisted Path path) {

    }
    @AssistedInject
    public SimpleData() {

    }
}
```

i removed the @Nullable annotation from the factory:

```
import java.nio.file.Path;

public interface Factory {
    Data create();
    Data load(Path path);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`@Nullable` does not mean that if you don't have a binding, then `null` will be injected. It only *allows writing bindings* to `null`. If you don't have a binding and there is no applicable JIT-binding, then injection will fail.

Your factory's `create()` method requires Guice to find an `@Assisted Path` binding, but it obviously can't find it since you've never created one, so it fails.

Honestly, I'm not sure if there is a clean way to implement such defaulting. Ideally you should mark `Path` with some binding annotation and add a default binding to null for it, but `@Assisted` already is a binding annotation, and it is not possible to have multiple binding annotations on a single injection point. You can try creating a binding for `@Assisted Path`:

```
binder.bind(Path.class).annotatedWith(Assisted.class).toInstance(null);
```

However, I'm not sure if it would work because `Assisted` can be special to Guice. And even if it will work, it is not very clean - there may be conflicts with other assisted factories accepting `Path`s.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found [a solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25738517/1594933) using `@AssistedInject`.

Answer (score 0):

I would have Guice implement some kind of internal factory interface, then expose something else.  Like this:

```
interface InternalFactory {
    Data load(@Nullable Path path);
}

public interface Factory {
    Data load();
    Data load(@Nullable Path path);
}

class FactoryImpl implements Factory {
    @Inject InternalFactory internalFactory;

    @Override
    public Data load() {
        return load(null); // Pass your defaults here
    }

    @Override
    public Data load(@Nullable Path path) {
        // Sadly you'll have to explicitly forward arguments here, but it's not
        // too bad IMO
        return internalFactory.load(path);
    }
}

public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
                .implement(Data.class, SimpleData.class)
                .build(InternalFactory.class));

        bind(Factory).to(FactoryImpl.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found [a solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25738517/1594933) using `@AssistedInject`.